# space between css menu hover

Tags: html, css

here is my css menu code. i see empty space in menu when i move mouse over menu item. i tried to find some solutions. i think you can help, please heeeeelp

http://www.picz.ge/img/s3/1312/13/f/f85b3e9ef429.jpg here is a picture of it

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="navcon">
      <div id="nav">
         <ul>
            <li class="first"><a href="main.html" href="#">&#4315;&#4311;&#4304;&#4309;&#4304;&#4320;&#4312;</a></li>
        <li><a href="registracia.html" href="#"> &#4320;&#4308;&#4306;&#4312;&#4321;&#4322;&#4320;&#4304;&#4330;&#4312;&#4304;</a></li>
        <li><a href="galerea.html"  href="#">&#4306;&#4304;&#4314;&#4308;&#4320;&#4308;&#4304;</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" href="#">&#4329;&#4309;&#4308;&#4316; &#4328;&#4308;&#4321;&#4304;&#4334;&#4308;&#4305;</a></li>
        <li><a href="kontaqti.html" href="#">&#4313;&#4317;&#4316;&#4322;&#4304;&#4325;&#4322;&#4312;</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
#navcon { 
    background: #4a4a4a url(menu_assets/images/grad_dark.png) repeat-x left top;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cee7f7 0%, #10a5da 50%, #0577a8 51%, #3ebdea 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #8a8a8a), color-stop(50%, #707070), color-stop(51%, #626262), color-stop(100%, #787878));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #cee7f7 0%, #10a5da 50%, #0577a8 51%, #3ebdea 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #cee7f7 0%, #10a5da 50%, #0577a8 51%, #3ebdea 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #cee7f7 0%, #10a5da 50%, #0577a8 51%, #3ebdea 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cee7f7 0%, #10a5da 50%, #0577a8 51%, #3ebdea 100%); 
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
#nav {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 56px; 
    position: relative; 
    color: white; 
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; 
    margin: 0px auto; 
    font-size: .9em;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align:center;
    list-style: none;

}
#nav > ul > li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

}
#nav ul li a {
    border-right: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block; 
    text-align: center; 
    color: white; 
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 1.6;

}
#nav > ul > li > a:hover { 
  background: #8a8a8a url(menu_assets/images/grad_dark.png) repeat-x left bottom;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #646464), color-stop(50%, #4a4a4a), color-stop(51%, #3b3b3b), color-stop(100%, #525252));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8a8a8a', endColorstr='#787878', GradientType=0);
  filter: none;
}
#nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
#nav > ul > li:hover  ul {
    display: block; 
    position: absolute;
}

#nav > ul > li:first-child  a{
    border-left: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
}
```

Comment: Just look here http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: perhaps add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your `li`s . it seems like the padding may be extending the content past its container.

Comment: Isn't that a margin?!

Comment: @Danko awesome post. that should be the answer to this question.

Comment: thak you @Danko bro you helped me

Comment: Note that this behavior is per the spec for `inline-block`, and is simply unexpected by many web developers.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/DMR6k/3

```
#nav ul {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 0;
}
#nav ul li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: I would argue that this is the (or a) better and more correct approach, rather than using `inline-block` and then having to work around the rendered whitespace "issue".